# How can I remove post dynamically via Linkedin API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I wonder how can I remove a post from my profile and company using API in my system. What parameter should I spend? Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There are no APIs available for removal of a LinkedIn share.  It has to be done manually through the web/mobile UI.